# Is it possible to add markers in component template only for tests in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wondering, if I have a component template, can I add some dom markers like class or id that will be striped in production build but would be available in tests? (Karma+Jasmine) For example

```
<div class='group'>
 <div class='row-1'></div>
 <div class='row-2'></div>
 <div class='row-3'></div>
 <div class='row-4'></div>
</div>
```

I would like to be able to easily find one of divs with eg `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".row-2"));` but yet I dont want those classes to be present in producion built application, so in production it would be like

```
<div class='group'>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

The goal here is to have easy way to add unique (or rather easy to query) identifiers that will be stripped out in the prod build. Any cumbersome solutions are not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to add `data-testid` properties to your elements. That way you are not interfering with the html id and can easily identify your elements.

```
<div data-testid="my-elem-test-id">
```

and in the test

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[data-testid="my-elem-test-id"]'))
```

Comment: Sure, but can I autostrip it?

Comment: There is no mechanism out of the box as far as I know, but you could create your own if you really need to. As as the data-testid is only used by ur test classes you could create some code snippet to remove them. But because they do not interfere with any relevant parts like classes or element ids, you could also leave them in your code. why do you want to autostrip them?

Comment: I just don't feel comfortable with leaking test markers .